# azure notification issue: apns works while template not response

Tags: xamarin.forms, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

Follow this tutorial ["Add push notifications to your Xamarin.Forms app"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push) for Xamarin.Forms development. After insert notification code in Azure backend and iOS, the notification template send out but no alert on device. However, the test sending of APNS shows the alert on the device. Appreciate any suggestion.

Here is my RegisteredForRemoteNotifications

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {

        const string templateBodyAPNS = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(message)\"}}";

        JObject templates = new JObject();
        templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
        {
            {"body", templateBodyAPNS}
        };

        /*
        // Register for push with your mobile app
        Push push = TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush();
        try
        {
            push.RegisterAsync(deviceToken, templates);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Register error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        */


        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);

        Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) => {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
                return;
            }

            NSSet tags = new NSSet(); // create tags if you want
            var expire = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90).ToString(); // set expire
            try
            {
                //register native notification
                Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
                });

                //register template notification
                Hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(deviceToken, "add_newbook_notification", templateBodyAPNS, expire, tags, (errorCallback) => {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
                });
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"Register error: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Because there could be multiple notification registration in one client app, theoretically both native and template notification registration should succeed here. However, I only receive the APNS but no template.

Comment: Here are some common misconfigurations to check for:

Ensure that your notification hub name (without typos) is the same in each of these locations:

Where you register from the client.
Where you send notifications from the back end.
Where you configured the push notification service credentials.

Also, refer this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer, which describes regarding “Diagnose dropped notifications in Notification Hubs”. You will find more options to diagnose the issue.

Comment: thanks for suggestion@Swikiruti. Actually I self check those docs but don't get any idea before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Messaging - RegisterTemplateAsync isn't working?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18683/azure-messaging-registertemplateasync-isnt-working) This link solves my problem.

> ***Note*:**
>
> *The problem was that this ExpiryTemplate wasn't clear for me. I did find any docs on that one, **but apparently, it's a DateTime formatted
>   as en-us.***

The expiry datetime **MUST be formatted as en-us**. Otherwsie, the RegisterTemplateAsync can't work.